# Correct way to defined AppFabric Cache client assembly references from a .net project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, appfabric, appfabric-cache

AppFabric Cache client side code required references these two assemblies that are part of the client installation:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client.dll
Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core.dll
```

Defining these references in Visual Studio 2010 will cause the assemblies to be copied into the project bin folder at build time, and subsequently redistributed with the our binaries. However the AppFabric Cache EULA makes no explicit mention of redistribution rights and therefore legally these files are not redistributable. I'm not sure if this is intended or not, however it is perhaps preferable for our clients to obtain and install AppFabric Cache for themselves at installation time rather than using redistributed assemblies which may be out of date and/or incompatible with the AppFabric Cache cluster (e.g. if it is using a different version).

However, the AppFabric Cache installer does not place the packaged assemblies into the GAC and therefore a client/customer will need to do this to allow our code to be able to reference them - the assemblies cannot be referenced in place (in \Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server) unless we explicitly refer to and load the assemblies from a specific path, which would be unusual.

My question then is - what is the intended usage pattern for referencing these assemblies? Are they in fact supposed to be redistributable, or should our customers be placing them in the GAC, or are there other options?

Answer (score 3):

Personaly, I use Nuget for referencing AppFabric Cache Client Librairies([Package Here](http://nuget.org/packages/ServerAppFabric.Client)). These assemblies are just an API to access your cache cluster. You can use them without any specific installation on the client machine.

These assemblies are part of your application. It is exactly the same when add a reference to another assembly, like Automapper,  Json.Net, ... it helps you to build your app without reinventing the wheel. So, include them with your build/setup, it will be easier to deploy.

Comment: This is old but it is worth noting that the nuget package is longer being updated.